# I can't add repository on Parrot OS

Tags: linux, shell, parrot-os

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Parrot/stable
```

This is the output when i try to add repository.

Command: `add-apt-repository "deb http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/repository wheezy main"`

i'm new on Parrot/Debian sorry i i'm too noob.

Thanks for help

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. ParrotOS has been made mainly for pentesting purposes, they altered the debian structure and made impossible to add other ppas. I don't have much knowledge about their implementation. It appears they separated everything. And their might be a work around for that I beleive.

Answer (score 2):

To add the repository to parrot software list, you need to checkout to `/etc/apt/` then copy the repository url to `sources.list.parrot` like so:

`cd /etc/apt`

`sudo -s #gives you root access`

`echo "deb http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/repository wheezy main" >> sources.list.parrot`

`exit #changes back to the normal user`

Disclaimer: Please be careful when you add software repos. It is one of the easiest way to break your system or add bugs to it

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for that. Actually, ParrotOS uses different files for source package links. If you open and see the file in sources.list by typing `/etc/apt/sources.list` everything is commented and there are no `deb` or `deb-src` links in it. All the links are stored separately in the `sources.list.d` folder see the files in it by typing `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` there exists a file for each source package. First change to root user.If you want to add new src link, you have to create a new file in that folder `<name>.list` and add the link to it.

Suppose if you want to add vs-code to the `sources.list`, then create a file named `vscode.list` in `sources.list.d` directory and add the link `deb http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main` to it.

Finally update by doing `sudo apt update` and then install `sudo apt install <package-name>`. For the vscode example use `sudo apt install code`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant try in /etc/opt/source.list.d/parrot.list

You can add stable repository
deb http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot stable main contrib non-free

Then sudo apt-get update